# How to cycle through HubSections in Windows 8.1 Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How we can cycle through the HubSections in Windows Phone 8.1? I have noticed that the built-in apps (People, Xbox Music, etc.) have this feature: Swiping the last HubSection to the left cycles back to the first section. But I cannot do it in my HubControl.

---EDIT:
It started cycling as soon as I added the third HubSection but does not work with two sections. But I notice that the Xbox Music app does cycling even with two sections. Does it use another another control?

Comment: Wrapping from Section <last> to Section 1 and vice versa is standard behavior on WP8.1. Check out an unchanged new Hub App. Not looping is expected on Windows (not-Phone) 8.1.

Comment: Apparently it works if there is at least 3 sections but the native apps also work with 2 sections. So I still do not know how to do that for two sections.

Comment: Have you tried to add two more sections that are the exact copies of the first two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will cycle through once you have three or more HubSections.

Comment: You are right. It started cycling as soon as I added the third section, but I also notice that the Xbox Music app does cycling even with two sections.

Comment: I don't think that the Music app is written using the Hub control.